# Invalid drive specification and how to restore with other server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've created an agent job in SQL Server 2008 with steps:

1. Backup
2. Transfer File (to another server)
3. Restore (to another server)

Step 1 backup has been successful, but when process transfers the file, it fails with message

> invalid drive specification

I've added IP of destination server on Windows credential, and I try to run the syntax in CMD it works:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'xcopy D:\folder\file_name*.ext \\desination_IP\folder\'
```

When I try with SQL Server 2017, it works. Is there any difference between 2008 and 2017? Please let me know

Then go to the next step restore, what I want is to restore the database from server A to server B. Example I have 2 servers with the name A server and B server i put the job in A server and the job consists of step backup, step transfer file and step restore. I transfer db to B server then i want to restore database in B server from A server with agent.

The question is, is that possible? Can somebody help me with the query to restore a database from another server? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is better suited to the [DBA StackExchange site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is `D:\` a local drive, or a network drive? If the latter, don't use the drive letter; use the UNC path. Drive letters are different for each user on Windows, and different users can (will) have different letters for the same location. That includes the SQL Server service account.

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server **2008** and **2008 R2** are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what user the SQL Agent service is running as, if it is Local System, you'll need to change it to an account that has access to the destination folder.